# How to fill NAs with the last date entered for each group

Tags: r, time-series, plyr, na, lag

I’d like replace `NA`s in my column with the last date entered for that `ID`. Below is the example for one `ID=1`: to convert `DATE_old` column to `DATE_new` column below:

```
DF =
ID       DATE_old       DATE_new
1        1/1/2018       1/1/2018
1        NA             1/1/2018
1        NA             1/1/2018
1        3/1/2018       3/1/2018
1        NA             3/1/2018
2 .....
```

I tried `na.locf()` which didn’t work:

```
DF$DATE_new <- ddply(DF$DATE_old, ~ID, na.locf)
```

Comment: I posted on my phone, and the formatting is all messed up! Sorry in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to have a reproducible example nest time, see [reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex).

```
# sample data (3 groups)
set.seed(42) # for reproducability
dates <- seq.Date(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 4, by = "day")
df <- data.frame(
    id = sample(c(1,2,3), 10, replace = TRUE),
    date = sample(c(dates, NA), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

# check the data.frame
print(df)

# using dplyr
# install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(new_date = max(date, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this replaces all NAs with the last date. I actually want the clock to restart when there is a date and not an NA

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example, may be we can use `fill` to replace the `NA` with adjacent non-NA preceding value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    fill(DATE_old)
```